# Beginning PhP: to protect quotes

Tags: php, html, double-quotes

I'm a PhP n00b. I'm reading some online tutorial, but I've already a question (a very basic question, I suppose):

I don't understand why the following code works properly:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Firts PHP page </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $userAgent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
            echo "<p>This is my awesome User Agent: <b>\"$userAgent\"</b></p>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and, instead, the following doesn't work although I protect the quotes inside the brackets:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Firts PHP page </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "<p>This is my awesome User Agent: <b>$_SERVER[\"HTTP_USER_AGENT\"]</b></p>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Does it throw an error? Does it not fully output?

Comment: For what it's worth, it's often best to not mix variables in with string literals.  This makes your code a real pain to read

Comment: Yes, sorry: there is an error: "syntax error unexpected " (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)"

Comment: The best would be if you read the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically found an edge case of [string interpolation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). While alphanumeric array keys need to be quoted in PHP, in double-quoted strings they need to be *unquoted*:

```
echo "<p>This is my awesome User Agent: <b>$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]</b></p>";
```

String parsing follows its own rules. In general, you can't drop random PHP code inside a string and get it executed.

Answer (score 2):

You could try one of these:

The curly bracket allows complex expressions within strings

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Firts PHP page </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "<p>This is my awesome User Agent: <b>{$_SERVER[\"HTTP_USER_AGENT\"]}</b></p>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

better yet, just use php for the piece you are outputting.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Firts PHP page </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is my awesome User Agent: <b><?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]; ?></b></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong usage of escapinng quotes. See and test thhis:

```
echo "<p>This is my awesome User Agent: <b>". $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] ."</b></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a variable within the string like this:

```
echo "<p>This is my awesome User Agent: <b>{$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]}</b></p>";
```

It is nicer and cleaner if you used

```
echo "<p>This is my awesome User Agent: <b>". $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] ."</b></p>";
```

Or without single quotes in array key

```
echo "<p>This is my awesome User Agent: <b>$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]</b></p>";
```

Comment: I can include a variable within a string also without brackets. Maybe only if it's a "simple" variable. I can do something like: 

echo "My name is $name $surname"; 

without encounter errors